# Unity - change scene after specific time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oculus

I am developing game for oculus Gear VR *(to put in your consideration memory management )* and I need to load another screen after specific time in seconds

```
void Start () {

    StartCoroutine (loadSceneAfterDelay(30));

    }

    IEnumerator loadSceneAfterDelay(float waitbySecs){

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitbySecs);
        Application.LoadLevel (2);
    }
```

it works just fine ,

**my questions :**

1- What are the best practices to achieve this?

2- How to display timer for player  showing how many seconds left to finish level.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is the correct way. Here's the sample code to display a countdown message:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool loadingStarted = false;
    float secondsLeft = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(DelayLoadLevel(10));
    }

    IEnumerator DelayLoadLevel(float seconds)
    {
        secondsLeft = seconds;
        loadingStarted = true;
        do
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        } while (--secondsLeft > 0);

        Application.LoadLevel("Level2");
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        if (loadingStarted)
            GUI.Label(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 20), secondsLeft.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you , but I want change label size , position to top right of screen

Comment: You can use the Rect parameter of GUI.Label() to specify the coordinates. To fit the screen size automatically, you can use the Screen.width variable to make the calculation.

Comment: `void OnGUI()
{
    if (loadingStarted)
    {
        GUIStyle style = new GUIStyle();
        style.normal.textColor = Color.yellow;
        style.fontSize = 30;
        style.alignment = TextAnchor.UpperRight;
        GUI.Label(new Rect(Screen.width - 100, 0, 100, 40), secondsLeft.ToString(), style);
    }
}`